# Change the asynchronous_metric_log check interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana, clickhouse

In the documentation can find the asynchronous_metrics_log default get metrics per minute,
but in my clickhouse,there are a number of metrics got per second.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49Nx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iMl5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09OQ.png)

Query 1000 row only can take 3 second record.

`SELECT * FROM system.asynchronous_metric_log order by event_time desc LIMIT 1000;`

In grafana,Working 2 hour can got 4 millions record on the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbjgA.png)

I change the config about this but It's unuseful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2z0v.png)

How to reduce the count about asynchronous_metrics_log? I take the Prometheus to clickhouse,Is the problem about Prometheus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few configuration settings for this:

asynchronous_heavy_metrics_update_period_s
default: 120 (seconds)
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#asynchronous_heavy_metrics_update_period_s

asynchronous_metrics_update_period_s
default: 1 (seconds)
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#asynchronous_metrics_update_period_s

I'm not exactly sure how ClickHouse decided between what is a heavy metric or a (normal) metric, but assuming that decision was made based on resources required

Comment: Thank you, the second setting is indeed useful for reducing the count and frequency of asynchronous_metric_log. I'm not sure about the usefulness of the first setting since it cant be observed any change.

Answer (score 0):

it might contain noticeable amount of rows, but still should consume a negligible amount of space.

```
select formatReadableSize(sum(data_compressed_bytes)) from system.parts where table = 'asynchronous_metric_log'
```

what problem it causes?

Comment: When ClickHouse is running idle, you can see through the top command that it sometimes consumes more than 10% of CPU. It can be observed that this table has a large amount of data that might be undergoing merging and compression. So, I think changing this parameter might help reduce the CPU usage.